build failure when trying to create image of my angular app
please i got error when run docker build -t app-front .
this is my docker file,I followed a tutorial and copy dockerfile but the error happaens in npm run build ,there is some point i would ask which is when given me the path of angular errors
(See "/tmp/ng-EAvZJS/angular-errors.log" for further details.)==>where can I find it please?

FROM node:14.15.5 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build 

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html

[it takes much time like this then i get error][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/HlIX0gnO.png

Are you excluding the host's node_modules tree with a .dockerignore file?  Is there more to the error message than just the file path?  What is in your package.json file?  Does the build work correctly without Docker?  That Node version is pretty old and isn't supported any more; does a newer Node work better?

I can't integrate package.jcon,really i didn't excluding node_modules ,and this is the error #12 0.714 > ng build
#12 48.41 Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
#12 346.4 See "/tmp/ng-EAvZJS/angular-errors.log" for further details.
#12 346.8 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#12 346.8 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
#12 346.9 npm ERR! Purple_angular_free@4.0.0 build: ng build
#12 346.9 npm ERR! Failed at the Purple_angular_free@4.0.0 build script.
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-26T16_15_24_772Z-debug.log

do you have idea where I found this file /tmp/ng-EAvZJS/angular-errors.log
